# How to make width auto with position absolute using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using `position:absolute;` now i want to make width auto (as per contents) but because of `position:absolute;` i'm not able to `width:auto;`

```js
$('.wishlistMessage').text('Your product added to wishlist')
                                   $('.wishlistMessage').show();
```

```css
.wishlistMessage{position: fixed;
   bottom: 25px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   color: #fff;
   padding: 12px 25px;
   display: inline;
   width: auto;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 5px;
   z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wishlistMessage">Your product added to wishlist</div>
```

Comment: You have shown part of your code with position fixed. Can you show relevant part of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element with `position: absolute` will fit it's size to the contents. Since you use `left: 0` and `right: 0` the element is stretched to both sides. Removing one of them (I've removed the right), would fix the problem:

```js
$('.wishlistMessage').text('Your product added to wishlist')
$('.wishlistMessage').show();
```

```css
.wishlistMessage {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wishlistMessage">Your product added to wishlist</div>
```